# How to fix my Even-Odd Program java code it writes even or odd but also the number

Tags: java

```
package practıce1.array;
public class PRACTICE1ARRAY {
    public static int evenorodd(int a) {
    @author Başar Ballıöz
        if (a % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.println("Number Is Even");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Number Is Odd");
        }
        return a;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

       int[] arr = new int[] {2,7,9,10,22,31};
       for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Element Of Index " + i + " = " + arr[i]);
        }    
        System.out.println(evenorodd(arr[0]));    
    }
}
```

Output:

```
run:
Element Of Index 0 = 2
Element Of Index 1 = 7
Element Of Index 2 = 9
Element Of Index 3 = 10
Element Of Index 4 = 22
Element Of Index 5 = 31
Number Is Even
2
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

I dont want to see value of number. I just want to see is number even or odd ?
I think it`s causing because of a mistake which is happened in method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `evenorodd` doesn't need to return the number given to it then, and you don't need to print the value given in. Change your method to this:

```
public static void evenorodd(int a) {
    if (a % 2 == 0) {
        System.out.println("Number Is Even");
    }
    else {
       System.out.println("Number Is Odd");
    }
}
```

And when you call it, don't put the method call inside a print statement.

Change this:

```
System.out.println(evenorodd(arr[0]));
```

to this:

```
evenorodd(arr[0])
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping

Comment: @BaşarBallıöz Glad I could help! You can accept and/or upvote the answer if you found it helpful.

Comment: But i want to ask what is the difference between writing with system.out   and just writing method 

Why it is also writing value of number when we write our method in System.out ?

Comment: @BaşarBallıöz The way you had it, the method was returning the value passed in to it. Then the Sop method sent that value that was passed to it to the programs stdout. Since you don't want the value being passed to stdout, we just don't call System.out.println.

Comment: @BaşarBallıöz Returning a passed in argument does not make sense most of the time. The caller knows what he passed to the method. Of course, unless this is done to allow method chaining.